# on click event is not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here i put my code in that i have ajax that fire on click event of dropdown in datatable , in my ajax i write tableid  on click of that particular field classname it is working fine in firefox but not worked in google chrome. i used 1.7.min.js i used it forr all my pages when i change it whole code going to be crashed so i cant change js. my code is here of ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function action()
{
    jQuery('#dyntable').on('click','.quickview',(function()
    {
        //show all hidden row and remove all showed data
        jQuery(this).parents('table').find('tr').each(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('hiderow');
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('togglerow'))
                jQuery(this).remove();
       });

        var parentRow = jQuery(this).parents('tr');
        var numcols = parentRow.find('td').length + 1;          //get the number of columns in a table. Added 1 for new row to be inserted



        //this will insert a new row next to this element's row parent
        parentRow.after('<tr class="togglerow"><td colspan="'+numcols+'"><div class="toggledata"></div></td></tr>');

        var toggleData = parentRow.next().find('.toggledata');

        parentRow.next().hide();

        var qty =  jQuery(this).val();

        jQuery.ajax({   



              url: "ajax/tabledata.php?id="+jQuery(this).val(),

              success:function(data){
                   toggleData.html(data);
                   parentRow.next().fadeIn();   
                },  
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Error occured: ' + errorThrown);
            }   
          });

        /*var qty =  jQuery(this).val();            
        var url = "ajax/tabledata.php?id="+qty;

        //get data from server
        jQuery.post(url,function(data){
            toggleData.append(data);                        //inject data read from server
            parentRow.next().fadeIn();                      //show inserted new row
                                                            //hide this row to look like replacing the newly inserted row
        });*/

        return false;
    }));


    //for map view of dropdown

    jQuery('#dyntable').on('click','.showmap',(function()
    {
        //show all hidden row and remove all showed data
        jQuery(this).parents('table').find('tr').each(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('hiderow');
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('togglerow'))
                jQuery(this).remove();
       });

        var parentRow = jQuery(this).parents('tr');
        var numcols = parentRow.find('td').length + 1;          //get the number of columns in a table. Added 1 for new row to be inserted
        var qty =  jQuery(this).val();          
        var url = "Mapdashboard.php?id="+qty;


        //this will insert a new row next to this element's row parent
        parentRow.after('<tr class="togglerow"><td colspan="'+numcols+'"><div class="toggledata"></div></td></tr>');

        var toggleData = parentRow.next().find('.toggledata');

        parentRow.next().hide();

        //get data from server
        jQuery.post(url,function(data){
            toggleData.append(data);                        //inject data read from server
            parentRow.next().fadeIn();                      //show inserted new row
                                                            //hide this row to look like replacing the newly inserted row
        });

        return false;
    })); 


}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove bracket from :

```
 jQuery('#dyntable').on('click','.showmap',(function(){...});

To :

  jQuery('#dyntable').on('click','.showmap',function(){...});
```

Comment: Wrapping an expresion in parentheses doesn't change the value.

Comment: @tyagi: i tried it but still not working in chrome it works only firefox

Comment: There's no difference between `function() {...}` and `(function() {...})`, just like there's no difference between `a+b` and `(a+b)`.

Comment: yes then what is the solution for it i need it to change onchange event but there are different ajax i tried to call in onchange event